# Persist a one to many relation in jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this two entities, in which the group as a list of permissions and a permission belongs to a group:

*GroupClass:*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
public class GroupEntity {

@Id
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "group",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<Permission> permissions;

public GroupEntity() {

}

public GroupEntity(String name,Permission ...permissions) {
    this.name = name;
    this.permissions = Stream.of(permissions).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    this.permissions.forEach(x -> x.setGroup(this));
}
```

*Permission class:*

```
@Entity
```

public class Permission {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String permissionName;

@ManyToOne
private GroupEntity group;

public Permission() {

}

public Permission(String permissionName) {
    this.permissionName = permissionName;
}
```

To persist the permission ,I did this:

```
    Permission p2=new Permission("permission2");
    permissionRepository.save(p2);

    GroupEntity r1 = new GroupEntity("group",p2);   
    groupRepository.save(r1);
```

And I thought that instead of that if I did this it would work,but It didn´t and don´t know why:

```
    Permission p2=new Permission("permission2");
    permissionRepository.save(p2);

    GroupEntity r1 = new GroupEntity("group");  
    p2.setGroup(r1);
    permissionRepository.save(p2);
    groupRepository.save(r1);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your mapping is incorrect, and you should have an exception when running it: there is no role property in Permission. Moreover, "it doesn't work" is much too vague. Tell precisely what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. And post real code that actually has the problem you're describing.

Comment: sorry my bad, the mappedBy was supposed to be group, when I was copying my code I changed it.

Comment: @JBNizet the error is org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.alert.interservices.uaa.Permission.group-> com.alert.interservices.uaa.GroupEntity

Comment: Well, the error is clear: you're trying to save a permission linked to a group, but this group isn't persistent (yet). So that isn't possible: how could Hibernate save the ID of the group into the permission table if the group isn't persistent?